# A four sided fair dice is rolled 10 times. What is the probability of two sides being absent and two sides being present?

Tags: probability, dice

When solving this question

> A four sided fair dice is rolled 10 times. What is the probability of two sides being absent and two sides being present?

I get the result $$\frac{{4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^{10}}{4^{10}}$$ 
yet the official answer is 
$$\frac{{4 \choose 2}(2^{10}-2)}{4^{10}}$$
Anyone who can explain where this $-2$ comes from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to exclude the possibility that only one side is present.  Given that two sides have been excluded, there are two ways this could occur.

Comment: Oh ok now I get it. I kind of feel stupid to not have thought about that. Thank you!